# how to use for loop for my issue

Tags: matlab

I have 2560 sample points. I want to calculate mean variance skewness kurtosis for first 512 points, next 512 so on. so totally 5 sets of output data .I want to plot 5 sets of values of mean , var , skew , kur in a graph.

I read a data from excel consisting of 2560 points

```
x=xlsread('dta.xls');
i=1:512;
y=x(i)
m=mean(y);
v=var(y); 
i=513:1024;
y=x(i)
m=mean(y);
v=var(y);  
i=1025:1536
y=x(i)
m=mean(y);
v=var(y); 
plot(m)
plot(v)
```

like this my code s going. I tried using for loop but I couldn't able to make it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried so far? Isn't the [for documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) already helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
x = xlsread('dta.xls');
ns = length(x); % number of samples
bs = 512; % bin size
bc = floor(ns / bs);  % bin count
m = zeros(bc, 1); % array of means
v = zeros(bc, 1); % array of variances
for i = 1 : bc
  i1 = (i - 1) * bs + 1;
  i2 = i * bs;
  b = x(i1 : i2); % current bin
  m(i) = mean(b);
  v(i) = var(b);
end;
figure;
subplot(211); plot(m, '.-');
subplot(212); plot(v, '.-');
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/vfF6Q6) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tobias:
Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems to me that `i=1:512 + 512*j` always starts with 1.
In the question it should be everytime the next 512. So I have change this to:

```
for j=0:4
    i=512*j+1 : 512+512*j
    y=x(i)
    m=mean(y);
    v=var(y); 
    plot(m)
    plot(v)
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, it should have been something like `[1:512] + 512*j`, but I removed the answer due to OP's lack of showing any effort